# How to match entires in SQL based on their ending letter?

Tags: sql, oracle18c

So I'm trying to match entries in two databases so in the new table the row is comprised of two words that end in the same ending letter. I'm working with two tables that have one column in each of them, each named word. table 1 contains the following data in order: `Dog, High, It, Weeks`, while table two contains the data: `Bat, Is, Laugh, Sing`. I need to select from both of these tables and match the words so that each row is as follows: `Dog | Sing, High | Laugh, It | Bat, Weeks | Is`

The screenshot is what I have so far for my SQL statement. I'm still early on in learning SQL so any info to help on this would be appreciated.

[image: Screen Shot Of Current SQL code]

Comment: Please tag with appropriate platform/vendor

Comment: My apologies, i was unaware that was required. Ive placed the tag in, let me know if there's anymore info i need to provide! As i said im still quite new to all of this.

Comment: `substr(<your column>, -1)` will return the last character of the string.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are a life saver!

Comment: Does the | mean a new row? Or do you need to return it all in one string?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend reading up on SUBSTR() for more information on why the below code works: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679

```
SELECT
    a.word
,   b.word
FROM sec1313_words1 a
JOIN sec1313_words2 b
    ON SUBSTR(b.word, -1) = SUBSTR(a.word, -1)
ORDER BY a.word
```